# Предварительный просмотр пользовательского ввода в textarea

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как с помощью jQuery или JavaScript реализовать, чтобы то, что пользователь вводит в `<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>`, отображалось в реальном времени в `<div class="preview"></div>`?

Как это реализовано здесь, когда задаешь вопрос. Заранее спасибо всем, кто поможет.

Comment: Также очень интересует, как избежать переполнения в <div class="preview">?

Comment: В смысле поставить там лимит, после которого писать "текст текст текст...", т.е. многоточие в конце?

Comment: Нет, чтобы после определенного количества символов происходил перевод на новую строчку. Почему-то приходиться два раза нажимать Enter, чтобы осуществлялся перевод на новую строку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#textarea").keyup(function() {
    $("div.preview").text(this.value);
});
```

То, что касается перехода на новую строчку по нажатию Enter, то это:

```
$("div.preview").html(this.value.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")); // кажется \r и \r\n не обязательно добавлять.
```

То что касается разбиения строчек по достижении определённой длины, то это всё-таки проще шириной дива отрегулировать.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Также очень интересует, как избежать переполнения в <div class="preview">?

Comment: Только я бы предложил использовать событие **keyup**, т.к. при **keypress** будет "запаздывание" на один символ.

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо, исправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто помог решить проблему! Но почему-то в <div class="preview"> нет перевода на новую строчку, а вместо этого ставиться просто пробел. Вот это сейчас пытаюсь преодолеть.

Comment: Для замены переноса строки на тег <br /> можно сделать так:

    $("#textarea").keyup(function() {
        var str = this.value.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />");
        $("div.preview").html(str);
    });

Comment: Огромное спасибо, теперь все работает правильно!